# Webcam light still on after cam.release()

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv3.0

I am using opencv and Python3 to read webcam.

The webcam light keeps on even though I released the webcam.

I am doing:

```
webcam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
webcam.release()
```

After the release command, if I try to read the cam I get: `(False, None)` but the webcam itself is still `<VideoCapture 0EE62DC0>`. I don't know if this is the issue, but the light keeps on until I kill all python script or python terminal.

I am on a Windows 10, python 3.5, opencv 4.0.1. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem. Was using python3.6 and opencv 3.4.2 (also on Windows10), reinstalled opencv-python version to 3.4.0.14. That worked for me.

Seems that there is a problem with opencv 3.4.2.

That specific version you can install by running the command:

`pip install opencv-python==3.4.0.14`

Answer (score 1):

Same here, using c++ and OpenCV 3.4.3 on Windows10.

Problem seems related to MSMF backend, disabling creating a environment variable with value:

OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF=0

solve the problem. Source: [here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12301#issuecomment-415801564)

Comment: I’ve opened the issue... now it seems they created a PR to address this issue in the new version....

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

My problem was solved when I changed the while loop condition from:

```
while(cap.isOpened()): 

    #Your code
```

with:

```
while(True):

  ret, img = cap.read()

  #Your code
```

Before changing the loop I also applied the following command on cmd prompt:

```
setx OPENCV_VIDEOIO_PRIORITY_MSMF 0
```

Please restart the PC once you applied the above command!

Hope this work for you too.

Cheers!!